# nstableview + cannot show partial file names

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstablecolumn

I am using Table View Control. In the control, I show File/Folders details, if I reduce the size of file/folder name column, it does not show partial file/folder name (whatever characters can be shown in the Column). 
If a file name has multiple words in it, if enough space is not there to show a word then that word does not get shown at all, instead of showing some characters in that word (Either a word gets shown completely, or not at all)

I want to know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Set the line break mode of the column's text cell, using either the Attributes inspector in IB or a `setLineBreakMode:` message to the cell.